# Is there any option to get Duplicate employee number from user table in Servicenow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am creating report to pull out Duplicate employee number from user table in Servicenow.

Answer (score 0):

**in a classless script include:**

Use Glide Aggregate function
groupBy employee number
addaggregate count on employee number
count > 1
return sys_id all the records

Report:
put filter sys_id IN javascript:

Answer (score 0):

```
var dpchk = new GlideAggregate('sys_user');
dpchk.groupBy('employee_number');
dpchk.addHaving('COUNT', '>', 1);
dpchk.query();
while(dpchk.next())
{

gs.print('Therefore the duplicate employees number is'+dpchk.employee_number);


}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.